# Terminology for class inheriting from dict

Tags: python

In this situation, would it be proper to say that f both *has* and *is* a dict? "Is" doesn't seem quite right. Does `f` *have* a dict in two different ways? What is the correct terminology for describing and thinking about this?

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "John"
        self["number"] = 42

f = Foo()

f.__dict__
>>> {'name': 'John'}          [A]
f.items()
>>> [('number', 42)]          [B]
f 
>>> {'number': 42}            [C]
```

**Edit:** I am interested in the way we describe these dictionaries. What are the appropriate terms to talk about this in?

Comment: f is dict. What now?

Comment: @Igor: No, every class instance has a `__dict__` and it contain all variables of the instance!

Comment: I erased my comment because there was already an answer, but I never said that it did not have a dictionnary. It has a dictionnary (the `__dict__` attribute) but it also is a dictionnary because it inherits from the dictionnary class.

Comment: I'd say yes, it both *has* and *is* a `dict`. You've adequately demonstrated that.

Comment: Just a reminder, if there's an answer you find helpful, feel free to accept it by ticking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Done. Thanks, Thane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an implementation standpoint, yes, `f` both *has* a dict and *is* a dict. You've adequately proven both `__dict__` and `f` itself exist as separate dictionaries.

However, I think the practical way to think about it is that `f` *has* **attributes** (via `__dict__`) but it also *is* a `dict` (via subclassing). You really shouldn't access `__dict__` directly; it's an implementation detail of Python classes.

Of course, Python being Python, there's no reason to hide internal details from the programmer. "We're all consenting adults," as the Pythonism goes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a language-agnostic statement, but there are two relationships between classes defined:

- **[has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)**, which is used when describing composition (like mixins or properties), and
- **[is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)**, which is used if a class is a subtype of another class.

Your class `Foo` **is a** `dict`, since it inherits from `dict`. It's not that it has a `dict`, since there's no individual property that is a dictionary, and it would also behave like a `dict` if used as one (a-la [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).

Comment: "there's no individual property that is a dictionary" -- well, there's `__dict__`

Comment: As clodion pointed, it does have a `__dict__` attribute, like all classes.

Comment: @Yann: not *all* class instances, for example those with `__slots__` don't necessarily have one. Which is just as well once you think about whether each instance of `dict` itself "has-a" dictionary, which "has-a" dictionary, and so on.

Comment: @Steve : True, I said it a bit quickly. I suppose there also datatype who don't have a dict (like int or float). Thank you for the precision.

Comment: Well, try adding items of dictionary! With `f.__dict__` you've got the variables. With `print(f)` you've got the items.

Answer (score 0):

Look at that:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "John"
        self.number = 42
        self.num = 4


>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.__dict__
{'name': 'John', 'number': 42, 'num': 4}
>>>
```

The `obj.__dict__` contain all variables.

```
>>> class cl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 12


>>> f = cl()
>>> f.__dict__
{'val': 12}
```